Tensorflow to Tensorflowlite conversion issue
Im trying to convert the Tensorflow model to Tensorflowlite model but it shows warning WARNING:absl:Compiled the loaded model, but the compiled metrics have yet to be built. model.compile_metrics will be empty until you train or evaluate the model.
How to solve this error?
I want to connect the tensorflowlite model wit android application,bt the tflite conversion shows error.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The warning you're seeing typically occurs when you load a pre-trained TensorFlow model and then try to convert it to TensorFlow Lite without compiling or training it first. TensorFlow Lite conversion requires that the model be fully built, including compiled metrics.Before converting to TensorFlow Lite, make sure to compile your TensorFlow model. This involves specifying the loss function, optimizer, and any metrics you want to track during training

Even if you're not actually training the model, you need to call the fit method with some dummy data to build the metrics. You can use a small subset of your training data for this purpose.Once the model is compiled and the metrics are built, you can proceed with the conversion to TensorFlow Lite:
